# How can I add links to the previous and next articles to my blog article on Voog?

Tags: navigation, blogs, article, voog

Adding the previous and next links to the blog articles in Joomla, Wordpress and various other php-based blog articles seems quite easy. However, how can I add such a feature to my Voog website? I looked around in their developers documentation but didn’t find any information.

Answer (score 3):

It's now possible with latest Voog update. See [docs](http://www.voog.com/developers/markup/objects/article#article_newer).

Source from Voog developers documentation:

**Previous (older) article**

```
{% if article.older %}
  <a href="{{ article.older.url }}">{{ article.older.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

**Next (newer) article**

```
{% if article.newer %}
  <a href="{{ article.newer.url }}">{{ article.newer.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no direct way to fetch the previous and/or next articles, but it's easily achievable with this code:

> first we have to find the current article to get the previous and next ones

```
{% for blog_article in blog.articles %}
 {% if article.id == blog_article.id %}
```

> note that blog.articles is sorted newest-first, so the next article actually comes before the previous one

```
   {% assign next_article_idx = forloop.index0 | minus: 1 %}
   {% assign prev_article_idx = forloop.index0 | plus: 1 %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

> then, cycle through the articles once more and fetch the previously found articles

```
{% for blog_article in blog.articles %}
 {% if prev_article_idx == forloop.index0 %}
   <a class="prev" href="{{ blog_article.url }}">{{ blog_article.title }}</a>
 {% endif %}

 {% if next_article_idx == forloop.index0 %}
   <a class="next" href="{{ blog_article.url }}">{{ blog_article.title }}</a>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The [article page footer](http://anchorage.voog.com/blog/dodging-chunks-of-ice-paddleboarders-soak-up-splendors-of-glacier-bay-for-4-days) in the Anchorage template is a bit more advanced, but uses the same method — you can see the code [here](https://github.com/Voog/design-anchorage/blob/master/components/site-footer.tpl#L6-L66).